# How to SELECT data from Oracle using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, php-5.4

Im using ORACLE to select the user that Lock a table, the query works fine, but when I try to retrieve the results, thrown me an error.

```
$c = ' SELECT oracle_username os_user_name, locked_mode, object_name, object_type FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT lo,DBA_OBJECTS do'." WHERE lo.object_id = do.object_id AND do.object_name='CLIENTS'";

$s = oci_parse($conn_s, $c );
    oci_execute($s);


    while($res = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
        //var_dump($res);
        $check = $res['OS_USER_NAME'];
    }
echo $check;
```

how can i retrieve the values;

Comment: Can you include the error that is thrown?

Comment: You can print the query and run in your database directly. so that you can come to know about kind of error. In future, you can able to resolve if you get what is the error and also if you feel it's easy..

Comment: Is it variable or table name V$LOCKED_OBJECT lo ??

Comment: Perhaps permissions?   What's the error...those views require more permissions

Comment: @zedfoxus thrown me this error: Undefined variable: check

Answer (score 0):

You Should have a comma `oracle_username os_user_name,` like this:

```
$c = ' SELECT oracle_username, os_user_name, locked_mode, object_name, object_type FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT lo,DBA_OBJECTS do'." WHERE lo.object_id = do.object_id AND do.object_name='CLIENTS'";
```

Comment: That wouldn't necessarily produce an error...it would just create an alias

Answer (score 0):

If you using two different tables and you are retrieving the column name, we want to tell to database which table column's we want to SELECT. For example lo.oracle_username, do.os_user_name.

```
$c = "SELECT oracle_username, os_user_name, locked_mode, object_name, object_type FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT lo,DBA_OBJECTS do WHERE lo.object_id = do.object_id AND do.object_name='CLIENTS'";

$s = oci_parse($conn_s, $c );
  $res = oci_execute($s);


    while($res = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
        //var_dump($res);
        $check = $res['OS_USER_NAME'];
    }
echo $check;
```